# Color / materials missing in Octane Render?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, octane-render-engine

Just downloaded Octane yesterday to check it out; it seems pretty good, but I can't figure out how to get materials to show up without actually re-making them.

Any help appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Octane and other third-party render engine have their own material system. You likely won't be able to use existing nodes from Cycles, unless the add-on implements that feature.

Comment: Hi Robert - I was able to create a cycles material and apply it & it rendered fine. Hmm....

Comment: Sounds like the problem is solved then? I'm not using Octane myself, hence I wasn't sure if they support using Cycles materials.

Comment: No, not really... though I think there is a material converter. I haven't had time to get back to it yet.